# Error in building unity 3d build for Windows Store with azure mobile service

Tags: c#, windows, azure, unity-game-engine

I am using `azure mobile service` in `unity 5.2.1f1` that is working fine for Unity Editor and building iOS project successfully. My problem is that when I build for Windows Stores, it raises an error

> ServicePointManager does not exist in the current context.

On commenting the line

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (p1, p2, p3, p4) => true;
```

it shows following error with multiple warnings in azure script on building
"

> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework,
>   but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the
>   latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C#
>   programming language,